# android.support.v8.renderscript error on ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, renderscript, blurry

I am using Blurry when I do ProGuard it gives me:

```
Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 

android.support.v8.renderscript.l: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.app.app-2/lib/arm/librsjni.so"
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.a(SourceFile:1347)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.b(SourceFile:1504)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.a(SourceFile:2454)
at jp.wasabeef.blurry.internal.Blur.rs(SourceFile:62)
at jp.wasabeef.blurry.internal.BlurTask$1.run(SourceFile:61)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add to your proguard-rules.pro file line below:

```
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 2):

In any modern app that uses Renderscript, you should add the following to your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

```
# Render Script
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
```

This will take care of apps that use the Android support library, as well as Android X.